# How do I get Intellij preview to display my custom view

Tags: android, layout, intellij-idea

How can I get Intellij's preview to display my custom view?  I have a very simple class that overrides TextView:

```
public class TouchableTextView extends TextView {
    int width;
    int height;
    int status;
    public TouchableTextView(android.content.Context context, String text) {
        super(context);
        setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        setText(text);
        setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.big_text_size));
        setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_dark));
        this.measure(0, 0);
        width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        height = this.getMeasuredHeight();

    }
}
```

I could sure use some help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to overload one of the constructors of View class. For example you may provide `TouchableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`. The IDE cannot instantiate your view using the constructor containing custom "text" parameter.

Comment: Thanks, ekudel.  I addded this and it works great:
        TouchableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }